# How to write two record to NFC tag, one Custom URI and one Text data?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, nfc, ndef

I wrote a small test application using the "[NDEF Library for Proximity APIs / NFC](https://ndef.codeplex.com/)" in codeplex.

I am writing 2 records into a tag: the first record is NdefUriRecord with custom scheme and the second is NdefTextRecord.

When tapping the NFC tag, my test application starts as exprected (based on the scheme defined in the first record).

However in order for my application to read the second record on the tag (after being started automatically), I have to move the tag away and re-tap, otherwise the application will not read the tag's second record.

Is this a normal behavior? How can I overcome this issue?

If anybody has another way to put 2 records on a tag, one custom URI record to start the application and the second a Text record to have some JSON data (as text) please let me know.

Thanks,

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Windows.Networking.Proximity;
using NdefLibrary.Ndef;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

namespace NfcShare
    {
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
        {
        private ProximityDevice _device;
        long _subscribedMessageId;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
            {
            InitializeComponent();

            // -> Initialize proximity device
            _device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();

            TxtStatus.Text = "Initialized";
            }

        private void LogStatusMessage( string newStatus )
            {
            // Update the status output UI element in the UI thread
            // (some of the callbacks are in a different thread that wouldn't be allowed
            // to modify the UI thread)
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () =>
                                        {
                                            if ( TxtStatus != null ) TxtStatus.Text = newStatus;
                                        } );
            }


        private void MessageWrittenHandler( ProximityDevice sender, long messageId )
            {
            LogStatusMessage( "Message published!" );
            _device.StopPublishingMessage( messageId );
            }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Custom URI Scheme

        // -> Override OnNavigatedTo() and check QueryString
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo( NavigationEventArgs e )
            {
            base.OnNavigatedTo( e );

            if ( NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey( "ms_nfp_launchargs" ) )
                {
                LogStatusMessage( "Launched Args: " + NavigationContext.QueryString[ "ms_nfp_launchargs" ] );
                }
            } 

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Write tags 
        private void BtnWriteTag_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
            {
            NdefUriRecord rec1 = new NdefUriRecord
                                    {
                                        Uri = "nfcshare:Hello+World"
                                    };

            NdefTextRecord rec2 = new NdefTextRecord();
            rec2.Text = "Record 2";

            NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage();

            msg.Add( rec1 );
            msg.Add( rec2 );

            _device.PublishBinaryMessage(
                "NDEF:WriteTag",
                msg.ToByteArray().AsBuffer(),
                MessageWrittenHandler );

            LogStatusMessage( "Publishing message ..." );
            } 

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Read tags
        private void BtnSubscribeTag_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
            {
            _subscribedMessageId = _device.SubscribeForMessage( "NDEF", MessageReceivedHandler );
            LogStatusMessage( "Subscribed for tag ..." );
            }

        private void MessageReceivedHandler( ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message )
            {
            var rawMsg = message.Data.ToArray();
            var ndefMessage = NdefMessage.FromByteArray( rawMsg );

            // Loop over all records contained in the NDEF message
            foreach ( NdefRecord record in ndefMessage )
                {
                if ( NdefUriRecord.IsRecordType( record ) )
                    {
                    // Convert and extract URI info
                    var uriRecord = new NdefUriRecord( record );
                    LogStatusMessage( "Read tag, URI: " + uriRecord.Uri );
                    }
                else if ( NdefTextRecord.IsRecordType( record ) )
                    {
                    // Convert and extract URI info
                    var textRecord = new NdefTextRecord( record );
                    LogStatusMessage( "Read tag, Text: " + textRecord.Text );
                    }
                }
            // Only read one tag
            _device.StopSubscribingForMessage( _subscribedMessageId );
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from the developer of the library through CodePlex.com. I copy his response here:

"Hi, 
 this is normal behaviour of the Windows Phone operating system. If you register to be launched via a custom URI protocol, the OS only sends the app the URI string. 
 The only possibility to read the whole tag including multiple records is to read the tag while the app is running. 
 As this is a limitation of the OS, there is unfortunately nothing that this library can do about it, and there is currently no way to overcome the limitation. 
 Br, 
 Andreas Jakl"

If somebody else knows another way to implement and solve the problem I presented, please do.

Thanks